# How to get the modify time of a compressed gz file using perl

Tags: perl, gunzip

I have thousands of gz files, each gz file has one XML file compressed.
I need to parsing all the files by Perl.
It works fine when using following Perl code:

```
my $fh = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new($file);  
while($_ = <$fh>) {  
    ...  
}
```

My question is, is it possible to get the last modify time of the XML file?
I've tried `stat($fh))[9]` but always returns the epoch time.

Thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
stat($file)[9]
```

The Gunzip stream doesn't have a modification time, only the actual file does.